# how to get a array class using classloader in java?

Tags: java, classloader

I define a classloader name MyClassLoader as such.

```
cl = new MyClassLoader();
```

I could use cl to load my class A.

```
Class c = cl.loadClass();
```

but how to load a class which is `A[].class`?

Comment: What is your end goal?

Comment: I want get a Class instance which is equal to A[].class. A is loaded by MyClassLoader

Comment: Why can't you just do `A[].class`? Do you want to do it at run time where you don't know what `A` is?

Comment: yes,"A" is in a config file.I use classloader to get A.class.Then i need to call decode(String s,Class<T> t) to get an instance of A[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `ClassLoader` implementation, `MyClassLoader` is properly implemented, you'd simply pass the canonical name of the array class to the `loadClass` method. For example, if you were trying to load the `Class` for the class `com.something.Foo`, you'd use

```
cl.loadClass("[Lcom.something.Foo");
```

---

You have to know that the class name for Array types is the character `[` appended X number of times, where X is the number of array dimensions, then the character `L`. You then append the qualified class name of the type of the array. And finally, you append the character `;`.

Therefore

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("[Lcom.something.Examples;");
```

would get you the `Class` instance returned by `A[].class` if it was loaded by the same `ClassLoader`.

Note that you won't be able to instantiate this type this way. You'll have to use `Array.newInstance()` passing in the `Class` object for `A`, for a one dimensional array, the `Class` object for `A[]` for a two dimensional array and so on.

Comment: how to use methods like decode(String s,Class<T> t) where t is A[].class? I had tried to load "[Ljava.lang.String;" , but throws Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: @user I don't know. I don't get any `ClassNotFoundException` with that class. What is `decode`?

Comment: I tried with it ,syntax like "[Ljava.lang.String"; can be used with Class.forName(),but can't used with classloader.loadClass method.

Comment: The question was how to load it with a `ClassLoader`, and these kind of names won't work there. Doing this with the static `Class.forName` method is not the same, as you have no good control over what `ClassLoader` will it use.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use [java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) like this -

```
A[] arr = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(A.class, 10); /* for example */
```

Comment: I want get a Class instance which is equal to A[].class. A is loaded by MyClassLoader. I think java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(A.class, 10) is an instance of A[].class.

Comment: Java arrays are first class Objects. I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: maybe arr.getClass() is what I want

Answer (score 1):

In Java 12, you can call `someClass.arrayType()` to get the "array of someClass" class. If you need a two dimensional array, that will be `someClass.arrayType().arrayType()`. Of course, you can load `someClass` itself like `Class<?> someClass = someClassLoader.loadClass("com.example.A")`.

I couldn't find a solution in the standard API of earlier Java versions, so I have written this utility method:

```
/**
 * Returns the array type that corresponds to the element type and the given number of array dimensions.
 * If the dimension is 0, it just returns the element type as is.
 */
public static Class<?> getArrayClass(Class<?> elementType, int dimensions) {
    return dimensions == 0 ? elementType : Array.newInstance(elementType, new int[dimensions]).getClass();
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
Class<?> arrayClass = getArrayClass(someClass, 1);
```

Kind of an ugly workaround, but... unlike with `Class.forName`, you control what  `ClassLoader` is used, and you don't have to write another utility to generate funny names like `"[[I"` or `"[Lcom.example.A;"`.